# unhide rows on sheet2 based on the values of checkboxes on sheet1

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I have a workbook with three worksheets. On the first worksheet the user is asked to click "relevant" checkboxes that relate to their project. Based on these checkboxes one thing happens but on two worksheets:

On the first worksheet (same as checkboxes)
1. related rows appear when checked and disappear when not checked. This I have managed to figure out using the following code for each checkbox (I have 8 checkboxes):

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    [22:25].EntireRow.Hidden = Not CheckBox1
End Sub
```

On the second worksheet
2. Same as above but on a different sheet, I would like the same result of related rows appearing when checked and disappear when not checked. I am not sure how to refer to another worksheet, and / or if there is a way to insert another line to the above.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `Sheet2.Range("22:25").Hidden...`

Comment: Thanks Ben, I'm not sure how to incorporate that. I tried adding it to the beginning - that didn't work. I tried adding a new line which did not work either.

Comment: `Sheet2.Range("22:25").Hidden = Not CheckBox1`.

Comment: Thanks Ben but that didn't help. I think i need some kind of "and" statement so that if the checkbox is selected on sheet one it performs the first step and then performs the second step on worksheet 2? thoughts?

Comment: I think you may need to do some research on how to refer to a Worksheet... either by its codename, as in `Sheet2.Range("22:25")`, or by its sheet name: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("22:25")`... note that code name and sheet name are entirely different